# Sequelize JS building associations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am building a user and role association using sequelizejs with postgres. Each user can have one role and each role belongs to many users.

I have setup the associations like this

```
global.db.User.belongsTo(global.db.Role, {foreignKey: 'role_id', as: 'Role'});

global.db.Role.hasMany(global.db.User, {foreignKey: 'role_id'});
```

Now, when I am setting up the objects and syncing sequelize like this in app.js it's not working:

```
var role = Role.build({ name: 'foo', permissions: 'bar'});
var user = User.build({username: 'sultansaadat', email: 'abc@abc.com', password: 'sultan123', isActive: true});
db.sequelize.sync().complete(function (err) {
if (err) {
    throw err
} else {
    role.save();
    user.setRole(role);
    user.save();
}
```

});

I was expecting sequelize to behave like all normal ORMs do but I think there is something wrong here or either I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly is not working?

node.js, and therefore also sequelize are async by nature. When you call role.save, that call returns before the database actually returns. You will have to wait for role to be saved and assigned an id, before you can assign it to a user.

```
role.save().done(function (err, role) {
    user.save().done(function (err, user) {
        user.setRole(role);
    });
});
```

Comment: I understand the async nature of things but the events were not firing up for me.

Comment: I wish sequelizejs documentation was better. Thanks for the answer :)